# How can we get better error reports for Ember?

Tags: ember.js

Ember has got to be the hardest-to-debug platform on the go right now. I realize some of this is JS's fault but still. Here is one that I just got:

```
Assertion failed: Error while loading route: TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'get' ember.js?body=1:3231
(anonymous function) ember.js?body=1:3231
defaultActionHandlers.error ember.js?body=1:31788
triggerEvent ember.js?body=1:31861
trigger ember.js?body=1:30774
Transition.trigger ember.js?body=1:29995
handlerEnteredOrUpdated ember.js?body=1:30645
(anonymous function) ember.js?body=1:30619
eachHandler ember.js?body=1:30667
setupContexts ember.js?body=1:30618
finalizeTransition ember.js?body=1:31035
transitionSuccess ember.js?body=1:30906
invokeCallback ember.js?body=1:8267
(anonymous function) ember.js?body=1:8317
EventTarget.trigger ember.js?body=1:8090
(anonymous function) ember.js?body=1:8384
DeferredActionQueues.flush ember.js?body=1:5563
Backburner.end ember.js?body=1:5654
Backburner.run ember.js?body=1:5693
Ember.run ember.js?body=1:6054
Ember.EventDispatcher.Ember.Object.extend._bubbleEvent ember.js?body=1:19569
(anonymous function) ember.js?body=1:19513
Ember.handleErrors ember.js?body=1:850
(anonymous function) ember.js?body=1:19504
jQuery.event.dispatch jquery-2.0.3.js?body=1:4677
```

Really? Every single line in the backtrace is within ember.js itself. How is this even possible? I know the error is caused by my code since it wasn't there a few commits ago. So now I have to go use `git bisect` or something to try to find out which of the 1000s of `get` calls in my code is causing the error.

Is there a better way? Ember's new inspector Chrome app doesn't seem to help at all...

Comment: Show us the code. Actually this error looks very straightforward, you are calling `get` method on non-existing `object` in your current route `router` or `controller`... I need one minute to show you where is the error, create jsbin.com

Comment: Too many files to upload to jsbin. If you can find it in a minute, great. My point is that the stacktrace should mention the file and line number where the actual error occurred, but doesn't. I'm sure this is due to some fancy JS footwork, but it's darn frustrating.

Comment: It says in the first line that error is in you current route, so really only two places to look for. You don't need to upload many files, just 2.